# Is it possible to find the index of <tr> in selenium?

Tags: selenium

For example, I have a table like this:

```
<tbody>
  <tr>aaaa</tr>
  <tr>bbbb</tr>
  <tr>cccc</tr>
</tbody>
```

Now, I want to find the index of the `<tr>` which contains the text `"bbbb"`. I already get the `<tr>` element by searching the text. Now I want to know if it is possible to get the index of the `<tr>` (which is 1). Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
List<WebElement> trElements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("tbody>tr"));
int trIndex = trElements.indexOf("bbbb");
```